# Making Calculation in two object arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have problem for makings some calculation for two values in two object arrays and get one array of the result,

***`if the _id is found in orders less the qty from the same _id in the Stocks if keep the qty as it is ..`***

Array 1 # orders

```
 [
    {
      "_id": "5e64cfb59726d72129e78aee",
      "qty": 10
    },
    {
      "_id": "5e64d0fe9978d443af7db86c",
      "qty": 14
    }
  ]
```

Array 2 # stocks

```
{
      "_id": "5e64d0fe9978d443af7db86c",
      "qty": 600
    },
    {
      "_id": "5e64cfb59726d72129e78aee",
      "qty": 60
    },
    {
      "_id": "5e64cfb59726d72129e78ab5",
      "qty": 650
    }
```

needed output :

```
{
      "_id": "5e64cfb59726d72129e78aee",
      "qty": 50
    },
    {
      "_id": "5e64d0fe9978d443af7db86c",
      "qty": 586
    },
    {
      "_id": "5e64cfb59726d72129e78ab5",
      "qty": 650
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to iterate on your arrays:

```
orders.foreach(order => {
  let stock = stocks.find(stock => stock._id === order._id);
  if (stock) {
    stock.qty -= order.qty
  }
});
console.log('new stocks', stocks);
```

Comment: stocks.find(stock => stock._id === order._id) returning always undefined

Comment: Answers are assuming you have an array `stocks` and an array `orders` which are defined. If so it works fine...

Comment: the _id value was coming from mongodb and not converted to string that was the reason thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do

```js
const stocks = [{
    "_id": "5e64d0fe9978d443af7db86c",
    "qty": 600
  },
  {
    "_id": "5e64cfb59726d72129e78aee",
    "qty": 60
  },
  {
    "_id": "5e64cfb59726d72129e78ab5",
    "qty": 650
  }
];

const orders = [{
    "_id": "5e64cfb59726d72129e78aee",
    "qty": 10
  },
  {
    "_id": "5e64d0fe9978d443af7db86c",
    "qty": 14
  }
];

const result = stocks.map(stock => {
  const foundRec = orders.find(order => order._id === stock._id);
  if (foundRec) {
    return {
      "_id": stock._id,
      "qty": stock.qty - foundRec.qty
    };
  }
  return stock;
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: be careful, I guess there may be multiple orders containing the same id, and this code wouldn't work in this case

Comment: orders.find(order => order._id === stock._id) returns undefinded

Comment: it will return undefined if it couldn't find anything. Isn't that what you need? when nothing is found, you use the existing stock?

Comment: no duplication in the _id coz it came from grouping operation

Comment: the _id value was coming from mongodb and not converted to string that was the reason thank you so much